# Laravel SQL Query with similar words search

Tags: php, sql, laravel

**What I am trying to do:**

Hello, I'm trying to build an SQL Query in Laravel, with the following criteria:

The user will enter values into 3 search parameters:

**(s1)** Company Name

**(s2)** Department

**(s3)** UserName / UserEmail

I have to write a laravel query that will get the "user_id", "company_name", "department", "user_name", "email", "manager_type" of all users who:

- Have (s1) in their company name name, and
- Have (s2) in their department name, and
- Have (s3) in either their email or user name.

**My Implementation:**

```
$list = DB::  table("company")
            ->leftJoin("user", "company.company_id", "=", "user.company_id")
            ->select(
                "user.user_id",
                "company.company_name",
                "user.department",
                "user.user_name",
                "user.mail",
                "user.manager_type",
            )
            ->where(
                "company.company_name", "LIKE", "%".$companyName."%", "AND",
                "user.department", "LIKE", "%".$department."%", "AND",
                "(", "user.user_name", "LIKE", "%".$name_or_mail."%", "OR", "user.mail", "LIKE", "%".$name_or_mail."%", ")" 
            )
            ->whereNull("user.deleted_at")
            ->orderBy('user.created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

**The Output:**
While this query runs, it gives only partially correct answers. Some of the values are also irrelevant to the query. I am really new to laravel, and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Can you add some sample data which demonstrates where the current logic is failing?

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses for correct usage of `where`

Comment: Hello do you need exact matching matching query use where. If not just see WHERE user_name LIKE '%or%' Finds any values that have "or" in any position in your field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where closure like this:

```php
DB::table("company")
    ->leftJoin("user", "company.company_id", "=", "user.company_id")
    ->select(
         "user.user_id",
         "company.company_name",
         "user.department",
         "user.user_name",
         "user.mail",
         "user.manager_type",
     )->where("company.company_name", "LIKE", "%".$companyName."%")
      ->where("user.department", "LIKE", "%".$department."%")
      ->where(function ($query) use ($name_or_mail){
           $query->where("user.user_name", "LIKE", "%".$name_or_mail."%")
                 ->orWhere("user.mail", "LIKE", "%".$name_or_mail."%");
      })->whereNull("user.deleted_at")
        ->orderBy('user.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hi! I tried doing it like the way you suggested. There was a bit of a syntax error, I edited it. Hope that's alright. ^_^